# Make video width 100% while maintaining custom height

Tags: html, css, video

I'm trying to place a video on my page with 100% width but any variable height, for example 300px;

I don't want the video to scale, I would like if the bottom of the video just gets cut off. I'll attempt to show this with a terrible image.

```css
video {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" align="center">
    <video autoplay>
      <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

Original Video:

```
---------------
|             |
|             |
|             |
---------------
```

Original Video with Custom Height:

```
---------------
|             |
|             |
---------------
| Cut off     |
---------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In css, set the height of the container DIV (in your example, sensibly named `#container`) and set `overflow:hidden`:

```
video {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    width: 100%;
}
#container{
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The video will still be proportional (aspect ratio) because the video element is `width:100%` and `height:auto` (the default).

At 300px, though, the video element will extend below the container div, and be cut off (because of `overflow:hidden`).